# Django ORM annotate products with customer score

Tags: python, django, orm, annotate

Consider the following Django model

```
Customer(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

Product(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

Score(models.Model)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

I would like to get a list of all products annotated with:

- total score from all customers
- score from the current customer only

I was able to get it working for the total score like this:

```
products = Product.objects.annotate(total_points = Sum('score__points')).all()
```

but I don't know how to add an annotation with only the current customer score (if the customer has reviewed the product, None otherwise). I want something like this:

```
cus = Cusomter.objects.get(pk=123)
products = Product.objects.annotate(total_points = Sum('score__points'),\
                                    current_customer_points= (Score.points where customer=cus and product = this).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ids = SortedDict()
for p in Product.objects.annotate(total=Sum('score__points')):
    ids[p.pk] = p

for score in Score.objects.filter(customer_id=1, product__in=ids.keys()):
    ids[score.product_id].customer_score = score

for p in ids.values():
    print p.total, '/', p.customer_score.points if hasattr(p, 'customer_score') else '-'
```